# Overwrite text with javascript

Tags: javascript, label

I want to overwrite some standard text from my CMS.

```
    <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/da-DK/listings" class="new_listing"
    enctype="multipart/form-data" id="new_listing" method="post" 
    novalidate="novalidate"><div style="margin:0;padding:0;display:inline">
    <input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input name="authenticity_token" type="hidden"
    value="vvEeH5tHhuGME4jNDPhw0o4w8KoWpwgchgrU7xG/7LQ="></div>
    <label class="input" for="listing_title">CHANGE THIS TEXT</label>
```

I want to change the text where it says "CHANGE THIS TEXT" using javascript. I know very basic javascript though, so I hoped someone here could help me.

I already have code that enables me to change a text with an ID, but this label doesn't have an ID, so I don't know how to go about it.

Thank you for your time.

The script can only be posted in the head section of the whole site (even though it's specific to one ingle page).

Here is my other script that worked for ID:

```
    <script>

    var texts = [];

    texts["new-listing-link"] = "NEW TEXT HERE";

    var interval = setInterval(function() { setText(); }, 100);

    function setText() {
    var textsCopy = texts.slice();
    for (var key in texts) {
        var element = document.getElementById(key);

        if (element != null) {
            element.innerHTML = texts[key];
            delete texts[key];
        }
    }

    if (texts.length == 0) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }

     </script>
```

How can I go about it? :)
I'm pretty sure I'm only allowed to use javascript and not jQuery

Comment: Java is to Javascript as Ham is to Hamster

Comment: Change it using class name just like you did with id

Comment: @Dragondraikk only that the connotation "Java" was in the case of JS intentionally ;)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way, no need to change what you've got

```
document.querySelector('label[for=listing_title]').innerHTML = 'New Label';
```

no jQuery bloat, no fumbling through arrays, quick and simple

querySelector works just like jQuery, but it has native speed and zero bloatage.

label[for=listing_title] finds the label that has an attribute "for" with the value "listing_title" ... so, while not guaranteed to be unique, not many forms have more than one label "for" an input

```
var texts = {}; // note {} not []
 texts["label[for=listing_title]"] = "NEW TEXT";
 var interval = setInterval(function() {
     setText();
 }, 100);

 function setText() {
     var textsCopy = texts.slice(); // why???
     for (var key in texts) {
         var element = document.querySelector(key);
         if (element != null) {
             element.innerHTML = texts[key];
             delete texts[key];
         }
     }
     if (texts.length == 0) {
         window.clearInterval(interval);
     }
 }
```

With the above version, you can mix id's as well as the more complex selectors ... so, your original substitution could be done as well in the same loop by adding

```
texts["#new-listing-link"] = "NEW TEXT HERE";
```

Note the '#' before the id

Another hint or two:

```
var texts = {
    "label[for=listing_title]": "NEW TEXT",
    "#new-listing-link": "NEW TEXT HERE"
}; // declare the text object in one go

var interval = setInterval(setText, 100); // this is equivalent (not exactly identical, but functionally identical to your code
// rest of your code
```

Comment: Thanks Jaromanda. It makes sense. I'm not sure how to insert this correctly in the script though. I'm sorry for my silly questions, but i'm pretty new to this

Comment: @Camilla - I see no script in your question, so I'm afraid I can't help

Comment: It's in a comment. Its the script I used to change another text which I was able to change by ID.

Comment: Instead of 
    var element = document.getElementById(key);
use
    var element = document.querySelector(key);

The rest is identical - of course "key" would be 'label[for=listing_title]'

Comment: <script>
  var texts = [];

   texts["listing_title"] = "NEW TEXT";
   var interval = setInterval(function() { setText(); }, 100);

   function setText() {
       var textsCopy = texts.slice();
       for (var 'label[for=listing_title]' in texts) {
           var element = document.querySelector('label[for=listing_title]');

          if (element != null) {
             element.innerHTML = label[for=listing_title];
             delete label[for=listing_title];
            }
        }

        if (texts.length == 0) {
            window.clearInterval(interval);
        }
  }

</script>

Comment: I'm think i'm really mixing something up here :S

Comment: edited the edit because I didn't notice a couple more errors in your code :D

Answer (score 0):

The script can only be posted in the head section of the whole site (even though it's specific to one ingle page).

Here is my other script that worked for ID:

```
    <script>

    var texts = [];

    texts["new-listing-link"] = "NEW TEXT HERE";

    var interval = setInterval(function() { setText(); }, 100);

    function setText() {
    var textsCopy = texts.slice();
    for (var key in texts) {
        var element = document.getElementById(key);

        if (element != null) {
            element.innerHTML = texts[key];
            delete texts[key];
        }
    }

    if (texts.length == 0) {
        window.clearInterval(interval);
    }
    }

     </script>
```

How can I go about it? :)
I'm pretty sure I'm only allowed to use javascript and not jQuery

Comment: Instead of document.getElementById(key) -> use document.getElementsByTagName["label"]. Note: This returns an array. Index that array depending on whichever label you want.

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (quick'n'dirty):

```
slice=Function.prototype.call.bind([].slice);
slice(document.querySelectorAll(".input")).map(function(x){ return x.textContent="Killroy was here"; });
```

Check the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bwoc182v/)

MDN on [Array.prototype.slice()](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

MDN on [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

MDN on [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)

If you need just *this* label, choose:`label[for=listing_title]` as in Jaromanda Xs answer

Answer (score -1):

```
var label = document.getElementsByTagName("label")[0] // If this is the first label of the page
label.value = "new text";
```

Comment: value i think is a property not method. `x.value = "New Label";` it should be like this.

Comment: label element does not have a value property either - you may be confused by jQueery